# How to ignore specific rules in Sublime Linter SCSS (Sass)?

Tags: sass, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublimelinter

I'm trying to learn how to silence a rule in [SublimeLinter-scss-lint](https://github.com/attenzione/SublimeLinter-scss-lint) (specifically `EmptyLineBetweenBlocks`).

For [SublimeLinter-csslint](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-csslint), I can run `scss-lint --list-rules` in Terminal, locate the rule I don't like in the output, and add it to the `ignore` array in SublimeLinter.sublime-settings (as below).

```
{
    "user": {
        // ...
        "linters": {
            "csslint": {
                // ...
                "ignore": [
                    // Following rules will be ignored.
                    "adjoining-classes",
                    "box-model",
                    "box-sizing",
                    "fallback-colors",
                    "ids",
                    "universal-selector"
                ],
                // ...
            },
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

For SCSS, there doesn't appear to be a similar way to find rule names in Terminal, and there's no scss-lint object in Sublime Linter settings. So…how is this done?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way I found to make it work.

- I created a file in my Home directory (`~/`) named `.scss-lint.yml`.
- In it, I copy–pasted rules I wanted to modify from the `default.yml` file located in`/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/scss_lint-0.39.0/config/`, preserving indentation.
- Close and re-open any SCSS files in Sublime to see the changes.

Example:

```
linters:

  EmptyLineBetweenBlocks:
    enabled: false

  LeadingZero:
    enabled: true
    style: include_zero

  MergeableSelector:
    force_nesting: false
```